# MySQL insert into table - syntax problems

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

```
$servername = 'edited';
$username = 'edited';
$password = 'edited';
$dbname = 'edited';

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$number = $_POST ['number'];
$manufacturer = $_POST ['manufacturer'];
$birth = $_POST ['birth'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO hgcasestudy (name, email, number, phonename, birthday) VALUES ($name, $email, $number, $manufacturer, $birth)");
if (!$sql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$conn->close();
```

I keep getting the error message: 
Connected successfullyInvalid query: Access denied for user 'edited'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I'm confused because $servername is not set to local? I think it's just out of syntax with other parts of the page. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed MySQL with MySQLi which is never going to work. You connected using MySQLi then tried to do a query using MySQL. Your query should be:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO hgcasestudy (name, email, number, phonename, birthday) VALUES ($name, $email, $number, $manufacturer, $birth)");
```

It should also be pointed out that you are vulnerable to injection attacks by using form values without ANY checking or sanitizing.